# SCRIPT5007. IE7 can not read functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am working on a part of a project, that changes address with on-change event. The address information is passed as json array.

Unfortunately my written code doesn't work on IE7. I have already managed to reach my goals with majority of usable browsers, but I can't figure out how to resolve this issue on IE7. Here is a fragment of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var remote_self_json_branches_text = <?=$remote_self_json_branches?>;

function selfOfficeChangeText(element)
{
    console.log(remote_self_json_branches_text);
    $(".self_del").css('display', 'none');
    $("#self" + $(element).val()).css('display', 'block');
}

function change_delivery_office_selection_text (branch_id) {
    var cityMap = '';
    if(branch_id == 1){
        $('.textBlockContainer #self .headerImage').removeClass('remote-self').addClass('self');
    }

    if(branch_id == 2){
        $('.textBlockContainer #self .headerImage').addClass('remote-self').removeClass('self');
    }

    if(branch_id == 3){
        $('.textBlockContainer #self .headerImage').addClass('remote-self').removeClass('self');
    }

    $(".cityBranch").css('display', 'none');
    $("#city" + branch_id).css('display', 'block');

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var mapUrl = '<?= $deliveryOffices[1]['mapCoordinates']?>';
    dom('delivery_office_title_text').innerHTML = remote_self_json_branches_text[1].v_title;
    dom('delivery_office_address_text').innerHTML = '<a class="mapPopup" href="' + mapUrl + '">' + remote_self_json_branches_text[1].v_address + '</a>';
    dom('delivery_office_work_time_text').innerHTML = remote_self_json_branches_text[1].v_work_time;

    var mapUrl = '<?= $deliveryOffices[2]['mapCoordinates']?>';
    dom('delivery_office_title1_text').innerHTML = remote_self_json_branches_text[2].v_title;
    dom('delivery_office_address1_text').innerHTML = '<a class="mapPopup" href="' + mapUrl + '">' + remote_self_json_branches_text[2].v_address + '</a>';
    dom('delivery_office_work_time1_text').innerHTML = remote_self_json_branches_text[2].v_work_time;

    var mapUrl = '<?= $deliveryOffices[3]['mapCoordinates']?>';
    dom('delivery_office_title2_text').innerHTML = remote_self_json_branches_text[3].v_title;
    dom('delivery_office_address2_text').innerHTML = '<a class="mapPopup" href="' + mapUrl + '">' + remote_self_json_branches_text[3].v_address + '</a>';
    dom('delivery_office_work_time2_text').innerHTML = remote_self_json_branches_text[3].v_work_time;
});
</script>
```

I am using the functions here:

```
<div class="win-xp selCont">
    <select name="delivery_office" id="delivery_office_text" class="post_lt_branch" onchange="selfOfficeChangeText(this); change_delivery_office_selection_text(this.value);">
        <option value="0">-- <?=t('Pasirinkite')?> --</option>
        <?php foreach ($deliveryOffices as $key => $val) { ?>
            <option address="<?=$val['city']?>, <?=$val['address']?>" value="<?=$val['id']?>" title="<?=$val['city']?>, <?=$val['address']?>" <?php echo ($val['id'] == 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?=$val['name']?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

I get this error:

```
SCRIPT5007: The value of the property "selfOfficeChangeText" is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

My guess is that the browser doesn't have enough time to load JavaScript. I am not very skilled with cross browser compatibility, so any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is that IE7 select elements don't have a value property. That error message is very confusing.... `"selfOfficeChangeText"` isn't a property!

Comment: "selfOfficeChangeText" is a function, that I use in select onchange property. Every option has values as id's that are passed with php.
value="<?=$val['id']?>" Probably it is harder to understand because my  code is not so tidy. But the point is, that I am missing some nuance with cross browser compatibility.

Comment: That's not what i mean. What i'm saying is maybe IE7 select element nodes don't have a value property. That doesn't mean a value isn't selected, it just means IE7's dom engine doesn't place the value in a value property on select elements. I'm just guessing at this point though because i can't recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that `IE 7` thinks that the value is null or undefined, because you are using incompatible version of `jQuery`. Try loading lower version of it, for example 1.4 and/or change the selectors syntax.

Maybe the `jQuery` selectors like `$("#self" + $(element).val()).css('display', 'block');` have problems in most recent versions with `IE 7` and it is normal to return null or undefined.

Comment: I am sorry, but I forgot to mention, that I have tried to debug inside the function, but I didn't get any result. So this means that the browser can't load these functions. Also, the js code is in the same .phtml file as html+php code.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to your `document.ready` function (and remove the onchange from your select):

```
$("#delivery_office_text").change(function() { 
     selfOfficeChangeText(this); 
     change_delivery_office_selection_text($(this).val());
});
```

It binds the change event on document ready.
I've also made it get the current value using `$(this).val()` in case that was giving you issues.